# How can we implement apex:param using dynamic visualforce components?

Tags: dynamic-vf-component

Im building a visualforce page using apex:dynamicComponent tag and adding fields from apex controller.

```
Component.apex.inputfield  roofShadingPreset = new Component.Apex.inputfield(); 

roofShadingPreset.id = 'shadingPreset1';

roofShadingPreset.expressions.value = '{!roof'+string.valueOf(i)+'.Shading_Preset__c}';

Component.Apex.ActionSupport asu = new Component.Apex.ActionSupport (event='onchange');  

asu.expressions.action='{!changeShadingValues}';

roofShadingPreset.childComponents.add(asu);
```

I need to pass a parametre in the action support event to the changeShadingValues() method. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can call a function with parameter from VF to your custom controller. I prefer using the remoteAction, but you can achieve this by using get and set methods as well. A naive implementation would look something like this:

```
@remoteAction
public static String changeShadingValues(String myParameter) {
    return  myParameter;
}

<apex:actionFunction action="{!changeShadingValues}" name="theFunction">
    <apex:param name="theParameter" value="{!myParameter}" 
</apex:actionFunction>
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I am not using the regular apex: actionfunction tag. Pls see the code i posted. Its a dynamic apex implementation.    Component.Apex.ActionSupport asu = new Component.Apex.ActionSupport (event='onchange');  

asu.expressions.action='{!changeShadingValues}'; I need to pass a parameter to changeshadingvalues method in apex.